# Swift 2 failing to cast UIView to GPUImageView

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, gpuimage

I'm trying to use Brad Larson's amazing GPUImage framework in Swift 2 and having problems. Being new to Swift (but fairly good in Obj-C) I'm not sure if it's a Swift or GPUImage bug or my ineptitude...

I've followed Brad's instructions for adding GPUImage as a framework in my iOS project (Xcode 7.0 beta 5), and on the whole things look good.

But I then as a test put in the few lines of code on Brad's blog (http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2014/06/30/exploring-swift-using-gpuimage) to try the 'tiny starting application' and although the app compiles OK, I get a runtime error (running on the device) of

```
Could not cast value of type 'UIView' (0x19842b510) to 'GPUImageView' (0x10016b548).
```

I've used GPUImage successfully in Obj-C in the past so I understand the theory but this is new... Any ideas? Is this just an early Swift 2 issue, or an Xcode beta problem?

(Incidentally, in the code from Brad's blog page I did change the cast syntax from the Swift 1 `as` to the Swift 2 `as!`)

Comment: Provide lines of code where you having that error or whole code example.

Comment: Are you sure the view in Interface Builder that self.view is pointing at has been set as a GPUImageView in IB? You often see an error like that if the class hasn't been set correctly in IB.

Comment: Brad - you're absolutely right I'd forgotten that. Thanks - all working nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer: ensure self.view is set as a GPUImageView in the storyboard. (Thanks Brad - unbelievable support as ever...)